# listview is not showing up

Tags: android

I'm fetching `PDF` from `firebase` and showing it with the help of `Listview` but the list is not showing up when I click on view `PDF` `button` it shows nothing.

Please let me know what is the problem in the code. It will be really helpful. 
The upload button works prefect just the view `button` shows nothing.

below is my code :

```
 public class View_life_science_pdf extends AppCompatActivity 
    {
    ListView lifesciencepdflist;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    List<UploadPDF> uploadPDFS;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_life_science_pdf);

        lifesciencepdflist = findViewById(R.id.life_science_pdfs);
        uploadPDFS = new ArrayList<>();

        viewAllFiles();

        lifesciencepdflist.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                UploadPDF uploadPDF = uploadPDFS.get(position);

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(uploadPDF.getUrl()));
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

    }

    private void viewAllFiles() {

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("uploads_Life_science_jour");
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                    UploadPDF uploadPDF = postSnapshot.getValue(com.example.publications.UploadPDF.class);
                    uploadPDFS.add(uploadPDF);
                }

                String[] uploads = new String[uploadPDFS.size()];

                for (int i=0;i<uploads.length;i++)
                {
                    uploads[i]= uploadPDFS.get(i).getPdfname();
                }

                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,uploads)
                {

                    @Override
                    public View getView(int position,  View convertView,  ViewGroup parent) {

                        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                        TextView mytext = view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                        mytext.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

                        return view;
                    }
                } ;
                lifesciencepdflist.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Current code doesn't have any click functionality. Hence it'll show only when the app screen is loaded. In case if you want to fetch only when a user clicks on a button, you need to add a `onclicklistener` and attach it with button

Comment: Yes this activity is after I click button to view pdfs

Comment: Add some logs and check if you are able to get the data from firebase